# XMLStreamReader Encoding

Tags: java, xml, unicode, xmlstreamreader

I have some characters from the Unicode Extension B Chinese/Japanese/Korean set in my XML:

But when I use streamReader.getText() it returns:

```
ࠀ
```

Does anyone know if Java's XMLStreamReader's encoding scheme for unicode characters can be changed?

It works with common East Asian characters, just not with the ones in Unicode Extension B.

Comment: How are you constructing the `XMLStreamReader`? What do `XMLStreamReader#getEncoding()` and `XMLStreamReader#getCharacterEncodingScheme()` return? What encoding is the XML actually stored with?

Comment: Hi Matt, the XML is utf-8 and XMLStreamReader#getCharacterEncodingScheme is utf-8 as well. XMLStreamReader#getEncoding is null
The XMLStreamReader is created by XMLInputFactory.createXMlStreamReader()

Answer (score 1):

when create XML Stream Reader, you can specify the encoding as UTF-8. Like the API below

abstract XMLStreamReader createXMLStreamReader(InputStream stream, String encoding)